# Google Places API - finding all ancestors of a place or storing them to perform broad(er) search

Tags: google-places-api, google-places, ancestor

I am trying to build a list of products, each tagged with a `sublocality` from the Google Places API.

I use the `placesAutoComplete` method from the API to allow the user to search for their `sublocality` while creating the product.

I then want to enable other users to search for products in a location, but this location can be a `locality`, `city`, or any other type that are ancestors of said `sublocality`.

When the user creating the product selects a `sublocality` I get back a list of `types` in the response, but none of these contain a `place_id`.

I thought there might be a way to find all ancestor `place_id`s of a place and store the array together with the product, thus enabling the user to find a product in a place, or it's parent place or it's parent place or it's parent country, etc.

For example, the user creating the product lists it in "Rochester, NY, USA". I want other users to be able to find this product when searching for products in "Rochester", "NY" or "USA".

Is there a way to find all ancestor `place_id`s of a place? Or is there another way of storing these values that I am overlooking that will enable something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After plenty of searching I have found the answer I was looking for. For anyone else trying this, this is what I did:

When making a `placesAutoComplete` call you can specify a piped string `result_type` to specify the type of results you want to receive. I changed my current `result_type` of **locality** with a new `result_type` of **country|locality|sublocality|neighborhood** and now instead of receiving the one, I receive a list of results, each of a different type, and each with it's own `place_id`.

A combination of the results (with duplicates filtered out) gives me exactly what I was looking for.